# Есть ли возможность в Navigation view сделать развертывающиеся меню?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-view

При создании Navigation view  для экономии места захотел попробовать сделать развертывающиеся меню(если это так можно назвать). Вот как например в Gmail почте кнопка еще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли такая возможность в android studio. И если есть то буду благодарен если подскажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да есть такая возможность. Для начала создадим менюшку в xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Дальше нужно создать xml разметку для заголовка пункта меню ( `list_group_header.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:textColor="#1f2124"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

и разметка для наполнения пункта списка (`list_group_child.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Следующим шагом создаем модель-класс для последующего наполнения списка меню:

```
public class MenuModel {

    public String menuName, url;
    public boolean hasChildren, isGroup;

    public MenuModel(String menuName, boolean isGroup, boolean hasChildren, String url) {

        this.menuName = menuName;
        this.url = url;
        this.isGroup = isGroup;
        this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
    }
}
```

Вот функция `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        prepareMenuData();
        populateExpandableList();

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

методы заполнения меню:

```
private void prepareMenuData() {

        MenuModel menuModel = new MenuModel("Android WebView Tutorial", true, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial"); //Menu of Android Tutorial. No sub menus
        headerList.add(menuModel);

        if (!menuModel.hasChildren) {
            childList.put(menuModel, null);
        }

        menuModel = new MenuModel("Java Tutorials", true, true, ""); //Menu of Java Tutorials
        headerList.add(menuModel);
        List<MenuModel> childModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
        MenuModel childModel = new MenuModel("Core Java Tutorial", false, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/7153/core-java-tutorial");
        childModelsList.add(childModel);

        childModel = new MenuModel("Java FileInputStream", false, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/19187/java-fileinputstream");
        childModelsList.add(childModel);

        childModel = new MenuModel("Java FileReader", false, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/19115/java-filereader");
        childModelsList.add(childModel);


        if (menuModel.hasChildren) {
            Log.d("API123","here");
            childList.put(menuModel, childModelsList);
        }

        childModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
        menuModel = new MenuModel("Python Tutorials", true, true, ""); //Menu of Python Tutorials
        headerList.add(menuModel);
        childModel = new MenuModel("Python AST – Abstract Syntax Tree", false, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/19243/python-ast-abstract-syntax-tree");
        childModelsList.add(childModel);

        childModel = new MenuModel("Python Fractions", false, false, "https://www.journaldev.com/19226/python-fractions");
        childModelsList.add(childModel);

        if (menuModel.hasChildren) {
            childList.put(menuModel, childModelsList);
        }
    }

    private void populateExpandableList() {

        expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, headerList, childList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                if (headerList.get(groupPosition).isGroup) {
                    if (!headerList.get(groupPosition).hasChildren) {
                        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                        webView.loadUrl(headerList.get(groupPosition).url);
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                if (childList.get(headerList.get(groupPosition)) != null) {
                    MenuModel model = childList.get(headerList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                    if (model.url.length() > 0) {
                        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                        webView.loadUrl(model.url);
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

и финальный шаг - адаптер для обработки списка меню:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<MenuModel> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<MenuModel, List<MenuModel>> listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<MenuModel> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<MenuModel, List<MenuModel>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuModel getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).menuName;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_child, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        if (this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
    }

    @Override
    public MenuModel getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();

    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).menuName;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_header, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

И все. Вот [первоисточник-туториал](https://www.journaldev.com/19375/android-expandablelistview-navigationview) где подробно описано что и как нужно сделать и еще один [туториал](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.com/2017/07/navigation-drawer.html).